# Get GridView Cell Format

Tags: c#, asp.net

After I added a Source to a `GridView` I want to know the Format of the cells from the grid. The `DataSource` is a `DataTable` with Columns in `String` and `Double` Format.

So I would like to get something like:

```
string Value = Convert.ToString(GirdView.Rows[j].Cells[i].....
Value = Double
```

Comment: provide more code. your description is not enough to understand

Comment: What i did was that i declared a DataTable as a Datasource for the Grid. The DataTable has a few colums. Some are Strings some are Doubles. So somewhere in the DataGrid Attributes there should be the info which cell (column) is what type based on the Format of the DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

If you are correctly getting the value from your `gridview` row cell as the code you have mentioned

```
string Value = Convert.ToString(GirdView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text);
```

Then you can check if the value retrieved from the cell is double or not by using the below code

```
double doubleValue;
string Value = Convert.ToString(GirdView.Rows[j].Cells[i].Text);
bool isDouble = Double.TryParse(Value, out doubleValue);
if(isDouble) 
{
      // double here
}
else
{
     //Other format here
}
```

Comment: Not only of the certain cell. I need to know the Format of the whole Coloun.

Comment: you can loop the column and put this code to check for double or any other format

Comment: Is there no way to check the coloum format from the datatable with the help of the grid? My problem is that I have colum in the datatable which contain numbers like 123,124,125 and so on (in String Format). An I have numbers like 23,4 ; 23,6 ; 1.453,23 and so on (Double Format). The grid seems to know the difference because when I do sort I get 1,11,123,23,24 for the numbers in string format and 23,2 ; 23,5 ; 1.234,23 for the double format. So there must be I way to get the initial datatable fomart from the gridview....

Answer (score 0):

You can format on the page itself. Either in a TemplateField or BoundField

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Numbers">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.Format("{0:C}", Eval("column")) %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Numbers2" DataField="column" DataFormatString="{0:C}" />
```

Comment: Thougt about this, too but i have Autogenerated columns.

Comment: Switch, you cannot do anything with autogenerated colums.